# Adding a jQuery Datepicker to a dynamically added <input>

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a method that creates a form in my controller:

```
...
sbReturn.Append(String.Format("<p id='planSetupAddNewEffectiveDate'>"));
sbReturn.Append(String.Format("<label for='txtPlanSetupAddNewEffectiveDate'>Effective Date </label>"));
sbReturn.Append(String.Format("<input type='text' id='txtPlanSetupAddNewEffectiveDate' class='plansetupdate' />"));
sbReturn.Append(String.Format("</p>"));
...
```

Is there a way to attach a datepicker to that text field?

I've tried the standard

```
$(".plansetupdate").datepicker();
```

and

```
$("#txtPlanSetupAddNewEffectiveDate").datepicker();
```

but neither actually generates the datepicker. I know when trapping events from dymically added controls (ie. buttons) .live is used (ie. xxx.live('click', function()...), is there something similar for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`.liveQuery()` plugin for this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/), `.live()` didn't *fully* replace it, your case is a prime example, you'd do this to get the result you're after:

```
$(".plansetupdate").liveQuery(function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```

For the why: The reason it isn't working currently, is because when you execute `$(".plansetupdate").datepicker();` what it's doing is this:

- Find all elements with class `planetsupdate`
- Make datepickers on them

But...your element wasn't there to find when it ran, it was added later.  `.liveQuery()` continues to look.  Altneratively, if you are loading this content via `$.ajax()` you could rig them up in your success or complete handler, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //Stuff
  success: function(data) {
     $(".plansetupdate", data).datepicker();
  }
});
```

This would look inside your returned data for `.planetsupdate` elements to add new datepickers on.

Comment: Hmm...The .liveQuery was throwing an exception, but I didnt realize I could wire up the datepicker after the ajax call returns. Kind of dumb of me :) Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant suggestion using liveQuery, this has solved a massive problem I was having.

Comment: @user275074 - Welcome :) I just posted an answer to a question of yours on the same topic, hopefully the simple approach helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should work!

Are you getting this from by ajax or during normal request.
Are you sure that your js code ir been executed properly (after input are created at doom).